# AS3 replace nth occurrence in string

Tags: string, actionscript-3, replace

When I want to replace "abc" by "xyz" i use the following command:

```
str.split("abc").join("xyz");
```

But what if I have the following string "This is just a test string"
and would like to replace only the second whitespace by "\n".

Comment: If i understands this correctly you want the resulting String look like this: "This is\njust a string"?

Comment: @Johan: yes. I want the second whitespace to be replaced by "\n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve on @fsbmain's answer, n-th occurence can be replaced in using '/(( [^ ]+){3}) /' (http://regexr.com?33nm5):

```
var str:String = ("This is just a test string").replace(/(( [^ ]+){3}) /, "$1\n");
trace(str);
```

The output would be:

```
This is just a
test string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://regexr.com?33nku) regExp:

```
    var str:String = ("This is just a test string").replace(/(.[^ ]+ .[^ ]+) /, "$1\n");
    trace(str);
```

output:

```
This is
just a test string
```